# Is there better way than this to find and remove additional space in string in JS?

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have the following function which detects if there is 2 space and removes one:

```
filterText(text) {
    
        if (text.indexOf('  ') >= 0) {
          return text.replace('  ', ' ')
        }
        return text
      }
```

is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Comment: That only replaces the first occurrence

Comment: You'll have to define "better," but you might just do `return text.replace("  ", " ");` without the `if`. Harmless if it doesn't change anything, very unlikely to cost anything performance wise (since strings are immutable in JavaScript and your code can't tell whether a string primitive has been reused; if it were costly, it would be optimized by JavaScript engines, so either they do or it isn't necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> If pattern is a string, only the ***first occurrence*** will be replaced.

You can either use [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) or try using RegEx with global flag.

The following example will remove 2 or more spaces with single space:

```js
text = `some  text,  more      text`;
text = text.replace(/\ +/g, ' ');
console.log(text);
```

If you want match exactly 2 space then:

```
text = text.replace(/\ {2}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: ...and tabs and vertical tabs and... It also does lots of pointless replacements (`" "` with `" "`). `/ {2,}/g` would make more sense. But whether this is "better" by the OP's definition...

Comment: Thanks for answer. can I chain lit like this?

text.replace(somePattern, '').replace(/\ +/g, ' ')

Comment: @Dave, yes you can but probably you can achieve that in a single regex pattern.

Answer (score 2):

No need `if` statement. Enough `replaceAll`

```js
function filterText(text) {
  return text.replaceAll('  ', ' ')
}

console.log(filterText('a  df sf s  fsf'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't need a function. You could write your code directly like this, assuming `text` is the variable in question:

```
text.replace( /\s{2}/g, ' ' )
```

The `g` stands for group and will find all matching occurrences in the String for you.